# create multiple table using sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-fragments

i try to create 3 table in my databse using sqlite, I navigate between the fragment through drawer navigation ,
DVD table works but for the CD table
i have an error : Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                (no such table: CD (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM CD)

```
 dbhelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity(), "abbes5.db", null, 1) {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("Create table DVD (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , nom TEXT )");
            db.execSQL("Create table CD (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , nom TEXT )");
            db.execSQL("Create table Livre (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , nom TEXT )");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    };
```

Fragment dvd

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

    dbhelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity(),"abbes5.db", null, 1) {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("Create table DVD (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , nom TEXT)");


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        }
    };
    listview= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    recherche =  (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recherche);



    db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DVD",null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                "nom"
        };
```

fragment CD

```
  dbhelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity(),"abbes5.db", null, 1) {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("Create table CD (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , nom TEXT)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        }
    };
    listview1= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    recherche1 =  (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recherche1);



    db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CD", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                "nom"
        };
```

Comment: first remove your application from 'device'. then after test again.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
db.query("CD",rest of all parameter null);
```

this will work same like you query

Comment: where should i put this line !?

Comment: instead of you doing rawquery